# illegal start of expression - line 25

Tags: java

I am new at Java so I apologize for missing the obvious.
I am struggling with the below code at line 25 AND 46.
@25 - Netbeans is presenting a 'illegal start of expression'.  That line is identical to others that are not in error (lines 30 & 37).  I ensured the variable names are syntax correct.
@46 - I am getting the error message 'class, interface, or enum expected'. This curly bracket is linked to the 'public class Purchase {' at line 12.

I have successfully addressed the other errors I had.  Thank you in advance.
Please assist...

```
public class Purchase {

    /* set values for invoice, sale amount and tax*/
    public int invoiceNumber=12345;
    public int invoiceNo;
    public int saleAmount=100;
    public double saleTax=0.05;
    public double saleTaxAmt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* @param invoiceNo*/

        public void setinvoiceNo(int invoiceNo) >> HERE IS THE FIRST ERRANT LINE >>
        {
            this.invoiceNumber=invoiceNo;
        }

        public void setsaleAmount(int saleAmount)
        {
            this.saleAmount=saleAmount;
            saleTaxAmt=this.saleAmount*saleTax;
        }

        /* Display method displays data values*/
        public void display()
        {
            System.out.println("Invoice Number:      " + invoiceNumber);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Sale amount:       $" + saleAmount);
            System.out.println("Sales Tax Amount : $" + saleTaxAmt);
            System.out.println("Total Bill:        $" + saleAmount+saleTaxAmt);
        }
    } >> HERE IS THE SECOND ERRANT LINE >>
```

Comment: In Java, you can't have a method inside a method.

Comment: Forgive me but how is that any different than Line 30 "public void setsaleAmount(int saleAmount)" that does not have an error?

Comment: The compiler is trying to parse as much as possible your code to not stop compiling each time it finds a syntax error (and hence output all the error in one time instead). In your case, it's possible that some fautive code could induce the compiler to interpret some invalid code as "valid". When you'll correct your first syntax error, it'll certainly highlight the second method declaration and so on. In this case, you cannot rely on them until you fix the first error.

Comment: That's because the first error causes it to think that `main` ended at the curly bracket that ends `setinvoiceNo`. Therefore the other two methods, it believes, are outside of `main` and legal - but then it runs into the extra bracket that belongs to `main` and doesn't know what to do with it. Move your methods outside `main`.

Comment: I relocated the main to a supporting class file in the purchase project. Thank you

Comment: Like I mentioned, the main is moved out into a supporting file.  This file now compiles cleanly.  NOW it will not 'println' at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to define methods inside a method. This isn't valid Java - you should move the other methods out of `main` and into the class itself.

Comment: I relocated the main to a supporting class file in the purchase project. Thank you.